# How to Set RTC in ES32 using NTP server?

Tags: wifi, esp32, web-server, time, rtc

I am working on ESP32 And want to set RTC from the NTP server. How can I get epoch value I have done this thing on CC3200 launchpad and used an NTP server library to obtain epoch value.

Answer (score 1):

this snippet from setup() sets on esp32 the NTP for internal RTC and uses epoch seconds to set time to TimeLib library.

```
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, "pool.ntp.org");
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < SECS_YR_2000) {
    delay(100);
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  setTime(now);
```

The ESP32 examples library in IDE examples folder has example SimpleTime.

Comment: Is `configTime()` a blocking function? Seems like it would have to be, seeing as how the Arduino is not a multi-tasking system.

Comment: @DuncanC, it is not blocking as you can see on the following `while` cycle. esp32 core is on esp32 RTOS SDK. arduino is one thread but `configTime` is a C function from SDK, so the function only activates SNTP